# date format conversion am to date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a help on how to convert `'09-07-15 07:41:01AM'` to `'2015-07-09 07:41:01'.`

I have tried below query but it is not giving accurate result.

```
select to_char(to_date('09-07-15 07:41:01AM'
,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
select to_char(add_months(to_date('09-07-15 07:41:01AM','DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS AM'),24000),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

It looks like you have to many Y's, and your M's ans D's are inconsistent!

I'm not sure if it should be `YY-MM-DD` or `YY-mm-dd`?

Comment: Hi, I am getting below output..0015-07-09 07:41:01 i want the output 2015-07-09 with timestamp. many thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer again ... note the use of `add_months` ... it adds 24000 months (2000 years) to the result ... but beware ... this will only work for dates in this century. It's a non determinant situation if you are dealing with other centuries since you have no way of knowing which century the date refers to if you only have two digits in the year.

Comment: Hi Many thanks for your help. It is working fine now. I have to deal with 19th and 20th century data. Is there any problem for this???Many thanks for your relpy.

Comment: Yes. You have a problem I'm afraid! How do you know whether 09-07-15 is 2015-07-09 or 1915-07-09? You can't know this without the first two digits of the year. I'm assuming you actually mean 20th and 21st century since 2015 is in the 21st century!